# In Harry Potter, Why Owls?

Tags: harry-potter

As we find out quite quickly, wizards in the Harry Potter world use owls for communication.  **Why owls?**

They can attract unwanted attention, such as:

- At the very beginning when even the muggles noticed: "bird-watchers everywhere have reported that the nation's owls have been behaving very unusually today."
- In the second year, when Platform 9¾ closes on them, Hedwig attracts attention by screeching.

Why not use, e.g. carrier pigeons?

Comment: well... why not!? Thank god it wasn't an exotic bird like a peacock as I have 2 owls at home now.. couldn't get a pet peacock!

Comment: i guess because the books were conceived in the early 90s, and SMS, twitter, status updates weren't available then. :)

Comment: A snow owl stuffed toy looks cute, so they can sell more merchandise this way.  They couldn't sell as many stuffed crows or ravens.

Comment: Plus, carrier pidgeons would be really boring compared to owls.

Comment: Also there's just no good choice: https://xkcd.com/1910/ xkcd #1910 Sky Spotters

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> Q: *Why did you choose the owl as the animal messenger in your books*?
>
> A. Because owls are traditionally associated with magic, and I like them.
>
> -- JK Rowling -- Scholastic Web Chat 2

[SOURCE: HP Lexicon](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/bestiary/owls.html)

Comment: `Because owls are traditionally associated with magic` I must have missed that memo.

Comment: @Xantec Yeah, I hadn't seen that before HP either. Slytherincess, too easy. I'll have to find a harder Q for you.

Comment: @Xantec -- I know, right? I'd not associated owls with magic per se, unlike black cats, bats, frogs/toads, and salamanders/newts. Owls have only been significant in one other canon I'm familiar with -- *Twin Peaks*.

Comment: So, as an in-universe explanation, it means that owls are more intelligent or knowledgeable in magic compared to to other birds, or at least are able to cope better with magic? There are numerous occasions where Harry could communicate with Hedwig much better than a Muggle (or maybe even wizard) can with an ordinary bird.

Comment: @Slytherincess Even Merlin has an owl: Archimedes.

Comment: @Alenanno I agree. JK Rowling was obviously influenced by earlier fantasy works dealing with wizards (e.g., The Once and Future King). According to Wikipedia's owl article: "The modern West generally associates owls with wisdom. This link goes back at least as far as Ancient Greece, where Athens, noted for art and scholarship, and Athena, Athens' patron goddess and the goddess of wisdom, had the owl as a symbol." More on Athenian owls: http://rg.ancients.info/owls/

Comment: @Alenanno -- The only thing I know about Merlin is that he was a Slytherin at Hogwarts ;) Seriously, I don't know the Arthurian stories at all, so Archimedes didn't occur to me. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I saw that now on Wikipedia... Why Slytherin? :D The owl for Merlin appears in the cartoon, I'm not sure about other versions of the story, honestly.

Comment: @Alenanno -- At Pottermore, in the Slytherin "welcome" letter after you register and get Sorted, J.K. Rowling tells us that Merlin was indeed a Slytherin at Hogwarts when he attended. She's being facetious, of course, but it is fun to think of him as a Slytherin. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I see... :D Indeed it is. And weird, too. :P

Comment: @Xantec all over the world, Owls are associated in a variety of myths and legends with the gods, wisdom, and death, they are seen as messengers with the "other world" in some Native American cultures. Even the brownie scouts story includes a talking wise old owl that advises the girls in how to find brownies.  Check out http://www.owlpages.com/articles.php?section=Owl+Mythology&title=Owls+Lore+Culture for just a glimpse of how important this is.

Comment: @balancedmama I guess I really did miss that memo. Thanks.

Comment: @balancedmama -- After **Alenanno** made the comment about Archimedes, I think it kind of slowly returned to me that Archimedes was a Disney creation for *The Sword and the Stone*, but I wouldn't have bet my life on it :D I don't care for Arthurian stories (although, I really want to see *Merlin*) so I wasn't sure if Archimedes was a real Arthurian character. It's been forever since I've read any King Arthur books or stories.

Comment: @Slytherincess: Archimedes wasn’t a Disney creation — *The Sword in the Stone* was originally a novel by T. H. White (it’s great fun), and Archimedes certainly appears in that.  As far as I know he’s original to that book though, not in any older Arthurian legends.

Comment: @PLL I saw your comment and decided [to find out for sure](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/23045/17) when the character of Archimedes (or any owl of Merlin, regardless of the name) first appeared, whether he's original to T. H. White's version or not.

Comment: Owls are obviously wise, after all, only an owl could tell us how many licks it takes to get to the center of a Tootsie Roll Tootsie Pop!

Answer (score 8):

JK considered owls intelligent and a symbol of wisdom.  Actually, many cultures consider the owl a symbol of wisdom, or a magical being.
Maybe she used this wisdom and magical heritage to her advantage.  The owls seem to understand their wizards when they direct them where to go. They can even read the letters they carry.  They're probably just a particularly magical bird. Useful, though a bit flashy.

Comment: `JK considered owls intelligent` except Ron's Pigwidgeon.

Comment: Ironically, owls are among the dumber of bird species.  I have that on authority from an actual owl-trainer.  Parrots would make more sense, but definitely look out of place in Britain.  My choice would've been crows, ravens, or starlings, which are both fairly intelligent and common in England - though Game of Thrones (the book) got there first I think...

Comment: Ravens would be the obvious choice:  Huginn and Muninn were how Odin/Woden gathered intelligence about the world.

Answer (score 6):

As a side note, it's not *always* owls that deliver messages:

> Harry had received two letters from Sirius since he had been back at Privet Drive. Both had been delivered, **not by owls** (as was usual with wizards), but by large, brightly colored **tropical birds**. Hedwig had not approved of these flashy intruders; she had been most reluctant to allow them to drink from her water tray before flying off again.

Source: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Tropical_bird

Answer (score 5):

Another reason nobody mentioned: **owls are naturally nocturnal**. <sup>[1](http://animals.mom.me/owls-nocturnal-4159.html)</sup>

It's quite possible that they began to be used around the time the International Statute of Secrecy was adopted. That way, **you could send messages at night, thus avoiding torch-and-pitchfork-carrying muggle neighbors**. Animals have numerous advantages over magical means of communication, but that's another question/answer.

This nighttime activity is most likely a big part of why they are considered magical out-of-universe. There aren't many birds as well-adapted to nighttime behavior as owls.<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nocturnal_birds)</sup> You could use bats, but they don't fly as well and are a bit too small for large packages.

Comment: Interesting point, but wizards' owls do seem to fly at least as much during the day too, which would actually draw unwanted attention towards them—see, e.g. the very first chapter, wherein the muggles noticed an unusual quantity of owls flying during the daytime.

Comment: Owl flight is also silent unlike almost every other bird alive, even flying though the day they could fly past you within meters and you wouldnt know unless your saw it. If one flew past your from behind the first you would know is when its infront (by that time you wouldnt have time to register what type of bird it was, visually)

Answer (score 0):

**Carrier pigeon** are called **homing pigeons** for a reason. They cannot deliver messages towards arbitrary recipients, they just return to their home base.

As Slytherincess' answer points out, owls have a certain "association" to magic, which allows them to locate, track and reach an arbitrary recipient. It could be that this means that at least one of participants need to be magician, so Muggles cannot use owls for communication purposes between themselves.

Also, Muggles use homing pigeons with great success (they are faster than owls). This might an issue for the self-proclaimed "magic elite" in the HP universe: they failed at breeding high-speed avian carrier, so they simply condemn the possibly otherwise superior animal as "too mugglish". This is, however, pure speculation on my behalf.